# Well-posedness of the Poisson equation with mixed directional derivative/Dirichlet boundary conditions

Tags: elliptic-equations

### The Problem

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ with regular enough boundary $\partial \Omega = \Gamma_1 + \Gamma_2$.
Let $K \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ a symmetric positive-definite matrix.

Consider the following Poisson problem with directional derivative constraint at boundaries:

$$-\Delta u = f \quad \text{in } \Omega$$
$$u = g \quad \text{on } \Gamma_1$$
$$\nabla u \cdot (Kn) = h \quad \text{on } \Gamma_2$$

Is this problem well-posed (*e.g.* in $H²(\Omega)$) and why ?

### What I tried

I tried to investigate:

- Uniqueness of solution using the method of energy. Let $w$ the difference of two solutions:

  - I tried $\int_\Omega \Vert \nabla w \Vert^2 = \int_{\Gamma_2} w \nabla w \cdot n$, but I do not know how to relate the latter quantity to $\nabla w \cdot (Kn) = 0$ on $\Gamma_2$ to show uniqueness.
  - I also tried $\int_\Omega \Vert K^{1/2} w \Vert^2 = -\int_\Omega w \nabla \cdot (K \nabla w)$, but again I cannot conclude.
- Existence and uniqueness using the Lax-Milgram theorem, and once again, I am rapidly stuck to concluse because of the last condition

Comment: In the book of Grisvard *Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains*  the case $n=2$  and $K$ is the identity matrix is considered.

Comment: Thanks for answering. When $K$ is the identity, it corresponds to the mixed Neumann-Dirichlet boundary conditions case, whose well-posedness is classical. I am interested in the case where $K$ is not the identity, but SPD.

Comment: Should be no difference but I haven't a reference.